# convert column in Gridview to checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview that displays a list of items and if they are checked or not. In the database the value is a boolean value. But in the GridView the column is displaying as true or false. How do I change it a checkbox instead of true/false.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Checked" HeaderText="Checked"></asp:BoundField>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "gvCVRTDetails_" + work.ID);
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();");

            HtmlGenericControl lnkShowHide = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("lnkShowHide");
            HyperLink ChecklistItem = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("ID");


        }
    }
```

I found an example of this for a DataGrid:

```
int count = 1;
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Item.Cells)
            {
                bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["IsActive"]);

                if (count == e.Item.Cells.Count)
                {
                    c.Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" " + ((b) ? "checked" : "") + "/>";
                }
                count++;
            }
```

But since I am using a gridview I tried changing the code to this:

```
int count = 1;
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(((GridViewRow)e.Row.DataItem).Row["Checked"]); //error

                if (count == e.Row.Cells.Count)
                {
                    c.Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" " + ((b) ? "checked" : "") + "/>";
                }
                count++;
            }
```

But I am getting the error:

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Create a template field.  Something along the lines of:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Checked">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckBox" runat="server" checked='<%# ((bool)Eval("Checked")) %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Edit: If you need to convert, try adding the (bool) explicitly, as above.  If that fails, then `Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked"))` should work, or you could use `<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Checked" />`... I tend to prefer the templates, though.

Comment: It's because you're doing ((GridViewRow)e.Row.DataItem).Row -- GridViewRow is a single Row of a GridView already, and GridViewRow.Rows doesn't exist.

Comment: ...I'm a little confused as to why you're converting to boolean, though.  You said the database already contained a boolean value.  If that's true, then you should simply be able to plug that in.